# How to Store value fetched from server in metadata tag of Android Manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am using a third party library for my payment gateway. The Api key needs to be entered in the metadata tag of manifest file. Now I am fetching the api key from my server instead of hardcoding the api key.
Is it possible to pass string value from my fragment file to Android Manifest's metadata tag's value attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt this is possible, the manifest file describes essential information about the app to the Android Build Tools. It is possible to [inject variables into AndroidManifest file](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables) at build time, but not runtime.